# Google Cloud Datastore create new Kind with REST http request

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datastore

I have gone through [Google Cloud Datastore REST API](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/reference/rest/). But I was unable to find the API that create new Kind. Now, how can I create new Kind with http request?

> Note: Client Library is not available for my favor language(Erlang).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You specify a kind for each new Entity. It can be an existing kind or a new one.

Comment: What is the API endpoint for creating new Entity of a Kind?
For example: To list all entity of a Kind we have:
POST https://datastore.googleapis.com/v1beta3/projects/projectId:runQuery as defined in https://cloud.google.com/datastore/reference/rest/v1beta3/projects/runQuery.

Comment: Use this library: http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/gcloud-java/0.2.6/index.html if you are not on App Engine, or this one https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/creating-entities if you are on App Engine.